# NODE.js and ORACLE, Problem with dbObject

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, oracle

I have a problem with Oracle Array in Node.js

```
    function simpleExecute(statement, binds = [], opts = {}) {
      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let conn;

        opts.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT;
        opts.autoCommit = true;

        try {
            conn = await oracledb.getConnection();

            const result = await conn.execute(statement, binds, opts);
            console.log(result);
            resolve(result);
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        } finally {
            if (conn) {
                // conn assignment worked, need to close
                try {
                    await conn.close();
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
        }
    });
  }

  module.exports.simpleExecute = simpleExecute;
```

In function simpleExecute everything works well. console.log displays the data correctly

```
{
      board_id: 242,
      name: 'School at School',
      user_name: 'David',
      user_url: 'ej',
      background_regular: 'red',
      background_thumb: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981806-ec527fa84c39?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=200&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyNTU3NX0',
      list_order: [USER_TEST.LIST_ORDER] [ 'WMCBQaBQtQ66' ],
      important: 0
    },
```

but when i passes the answer back to the getAll function

```
async function getAll(user) {
    user.user_id = parseInt(user.user_id, 10);

    const query = `SELECT
        BOARD_ID "board_id",
        NAME "name",
        t.background.user_name "user_name" , 
        t.background.user_url "user_url" , 
        t.background.background_regular "background_regular" , 
        t.background.background_thumb "background_thumb" ,  
        t.LIST_ORDER "list_order",
        IMPORTANT "important"
        from TO_DO_TABLE t
        WHERE USER_ID=:user_id`;

    const result = await database.simpleExecute(query, user);
    console.log(result);

    return result.rows;
}
```

Console.log displays the Error

```
Error: DPI-1010: not connected
    at DbObject._toPojo (C:\Users\David\Desktop\BD_2020\back-end\node_modules\oracledb\lib\dbObject.js:48:19)
    at Proxy.[nodejs.util.inspect.custom] (C:\Users\David\Desktop\BD_2020\back-end\node_modules\oracledb\lib\dbObject.js:63:54)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:693:31)
    at formatProperty (internal/util/inspect.js:1558:11)
    at formatRaw (internal/util/inspect.js:933:9)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:721:10)
    at formatProperty (internal/util/inspect.js:1558:11)
    at formatArray (internal/util/inspect.js:1380:17)
    at formatRaw (internal/util/inspect.js:930:14)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:721:10)
```

Problem is with this Oracle Array

```
list_order: [USER_TEST.LIST_ORDER] [ 'WMCBQaBQtQ66' ]
```

I have no idea what's going on, why I can display this ARRAY in one function and not in the other

EDIT:

If I do not close the connection after performing the function simpleExecute, everything is fine, but is there any possibility to pull out this data and push it higher despite closing the connection

Answer (score 0):

Connections must remain open while you are accessing the underlying object.  Same with LOBs, if you are streaming them.  This is one reason why we have gone away from putting an inbuilt 'simpleexecute' function in the node-oracledb API.

Comment: David, did you still need help with this or was Chris' comment sufficient?